# How to compare $\root 3 \of 2 + \root \of 3$ and $3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> How to compare $\root 3 \of 2 + \root \of 3$ and $3$?

I tried to make them as 6th root, but it doesn't work. I'm completely lost.

Comment: See the [mathjax reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint : Calculate $(3-\sqrt{3})^3$

Comment: It doesnt make sence for me...

Comment: its $54 - 30 \root \of 3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is $\root 3\of 2 +\sqrt 3\; ?\; 3$, where you have to determine if $?$ is $>$, $<$ or $=$.

$$\root 3 \of 2\;?\;(3-\sqrt 3)$$
$$ 2\;?\;(3-\sqrt 3)^3 = 54-30\sqrt 3$$
$$ 1\;?\; 27-15\sqrt 3$$
$$ 15\sqrt 3\;?\;26$$
$$(15\sqrt 3)^2\;?\;26^2$$
$$225\times 3 = 675\;?\;676$$

So $?$ is $<$, that is $\root 3\of 2 +\sqrt 3< 3$.

Comment: thanks, i got answer already using same path, thanks for the hint from @Peter

Answer (score 3):

To compare $\sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt 3$ and $3$ better compare

$\sqrt[3]{2} $ and $3 - \sqrt 3$

cube both numbers

$2$ and $54-30 \sqrt{3}$

now subtract $2$ and add $30 \sqrt{3}$ to both sides

$30 \sqrt{3}$ and $52$

square both sides

$2700<2704$ thus $\sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt 3<3$

Comment: @user thank you! Need one more coffee...

Answer (score -1):

We have
$$
\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{3} < \frac{42}{100} = \frac{21}{50},
\quad
\frac{\sqrt 3}{3} < \frac{58}{100} = \frac{29}{50}
\implies
\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt 3}{3} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{3} + \frac{\sqrt 3}{3} < 1
$$
Prove this by removing the radicals and cross multiplying.

These approximations come from the decimal values.

For the sake of curiosity, the simplest approximations that work in the argument above come from their continued fractions:
$$
\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{3} < \frac{8}{19},
\quad
\frac{\sqrt 3}{3} < \frac{11}{19}
$$

Comment: Why do you think, or how do you think, your very first inequality is immediate or pretty easy to see? And alos the 2nd one, of course.

Comment: @DonAntonio, the first set of inequalities comes from decimal values: $\sqrt[3]{2} \approx 1.26$ and $\sqrt3 \approx 1.73$. The second set was found with a program.

Comment: Exactly my point: I don't think the OP can use such things. If he could use some program, or even a simple calculator, he wouldn't have any problem at all, would he?